# How do you create a new row for a block in a database or a new model for each in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, model

I'm creating a baby stork party / baby shower gift registry app with Rails where the mom to bee creates a registry and the other friends can nominate gifts etc.

I'm using Rails and after studying a few Rails books I'm getting to intermediate. The problem is I can't figure out how to create a fixed baby registry where the mom can just choose quantity, color, brand next to each product category and save.

I created the model Registry and the columns quantity, brand, color etc. After a while I figured this won't work as how will a name each category (row) for those columns and keep it fixed (in a sense) and separate almost like a form? It almost feels like I need a separate model for each category but that can't be the most effective way?

Its really hard to explain, but I'm stuck or missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing a many-to-many relationship between a registry item, and a trait.  So an item can have many traits (color, quality, brand) and a trait can have many items (so you can find all the items by color, quality, etc).

Checkout:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

```
class Color
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Items
  has_and_belongs_to_many :colors
end
```

Will allow you to do things like:

```
item = Item.find 1
color = Color.find_by_name 'blue'
item.colors << color

# all the items for a color
color.items    # item 1

# all the colors for an item
item.colors    # blue
```

Structuring your form(s) to support this will require some work, I suggest googling around for examples.

Comment: No prob, click the check mark to mark it as correct if it worked for you. ;)

Comment: Hi again, I created a has many_through with Registry, Item and Trait models. I also figured out I have to use nested_forms to make the app as per original question. I just can't get the New, Create action working right for items. There are 3 items and each has many traits(color, size, quantity) and they all belong to a registry. Am Igoing the right direction with this?

Comment: The item is the main controller with traits nested table running through it. I can wrap registry around everything later. I have the new rails recipes handbook - that's where I got all the ideas.